# C language, my function is not returning a value, can not fix it

Tags: c, function, return-value

my function:

```
int compare(int A, int B){

  if(A>B){
    return A
  }
  else {
    return B
  }
}


int main(void)
{

  int A;
  int B;

  scanf("%d", &A);
  scanf("%d", &B);

  compare (A,B);
}
```

but it is not returning, if i write print instead of return however, it works

Comment: This can't even compile.

Comment: You don't do anything with the return value. `compare (A,B);` invokes the function and discards the return value. You'd want something like `int result = compare (A,B);` and then use `result` somehow (print it, for example).

Comment: It (when corrected) *does* return a value, but you ignore it.

Comment: int result = compare(A, B);

Comment: @EStudent Remove the semicolon in the declaration  int main(void);

Comment: There is a closing brace `}` missing at the end of the function, and two missing `;` in the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is correctly returning<sup>[1]</sup>; you simply don't do anything with the returned value. For example, if you wanted to print the returned value to stdout, you could use the following:

```
printf("%d\n", compare(A,B));
```

---

1. If it wasn't for the missing includes, the stray semi-colon, the two missing semi-colons, and the missing right brace that prevent the code from even compiling.

Comment: the missing `return 0` is perfectly legal, but the two missing `;` in the function are not.

Comment: thanks, my code is compiling but i wrote it here accidentally with wrong syntax. and i dont know how to edit properly. my main problem was that returning does not give a value to the console, but when i write printf instead of return then it works. but i want to use return

Comment: @EStudent it's best to copy/paste the actual code, than to risk typos.

Comment: @Weather Vane, Re "*the missing return 0 is perfectly legal*", Are you saying `main` special? Because it's UB in other functions.

Comment: Yes, `main` is special. Since C99, `main` is the one function that does not need to explicitly return a value. It defaults to an implied `return 0;`

Comment: @EStudent, Don't post code you haven't run. If we have no idea what your code actually looks like, how can we possibly tell you what's wrong with it? Forcing us to guess is a huge waste of time and energy, and we couldn't be telling you things that are completely wrong for you. Assuming we bother to reply at all. And of course, we hate being lied to ("if i write print instead of return however, it works" is patently false.)